# Java Coding areaCircle

Tags: java, area

I have an assignment for school where I have to create a program that will calculate the area of a circle given four points, but when I invoke the method areaCircle in main, nothing happens. It doesn't calculate the area.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader;
    reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the coordinates of a point on the outside of a circle.");
    System.out.println("x-coordinate: ");
    int x1 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("y-coordinate: ");
    int y1 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the center point of the circle.");
    System.out.println("x-coordinate: ");
    int x2 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("y-coordinate:");
    int y2 = reader.nextInt();
    areaCircle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

public static double distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    double dx = x2 - x1;
    double dy = y2 - y1;
    double dsquared = dx * dx + dy * dy;
    double result = Math.sqrt(dsquared);
    return result;
}

public static double areaCircle(int radius, double area) {
    area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    return area;
}

public static double areaCircle(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
    double radius = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    double area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    return area;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only to print the result, at the moment you are only calculating it.

Instead of

```
areaCircle (x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

write

```
System.out.println("The area is: " + areaCircle (x1, y1, x2, y2));
```

Comment: If it solves your problem you can upvote it and flag it as the right answer with the green check. Thank you.

Comment: @Jackie Alternatively, you could have `double area = areaCircle(x1, y1, x2, y2);` followed by `System.out.println("The area is " + area");`

Comment: @Trobbins: if he will change the method as you said the best is to change also method signature and name to printArea returning void. A method should be always reflecting its name.

Comment: @Davide I wasn't implying a method change. The above code will have been put in the `main` method.

Comment: @Trobbins: Ok perfect.